# SELECT UnitCost on MAX(OrderDate) from another table

Tags: sql, date, max, openedge, progress-db

We have an ERP system with a Purchase Order header table (POHeader) and a Purchase Order lines table (PODetail). There are hundreds of thousands of POLines where many, many parts have been repeatedly purchased over several years. I need to find the UnitCost of each part purchased from the last time it was purchased (max(OrderDate) of the PO).

I have been playing with [SQL MAX(DATE) Order Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992917/sql-maxdate-order-number) for which I have nearly the same identical requirements. If we look at the solution code in that thread:

```
SELECT t.ClientId, t.MaxDate, o.OrderNumber
FROM (SELECT ClientId, MAX(Date) as MaxDate
          FROM dbo.tblOrders
          GROUP BY ClientId) t
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblOrders o
        ON t.ClientId = o.ClientId
            AND t.MaxDate = o.Date
```

My needs are identical where my Part Number is his ClientId and my UnitCost is his OrderNumber. A quick substitution would give me something like this:

```
SELECT t.PartNum, t.MaxDate, o.UnitCost
FROM (SELECT PartNum, MAX(OrderDate) as MaxDate
          FROM POdetail
          GROUP BY PartNum) t
    INNER JOIN POdetail o
        ON t.PartNum = o.PartNum
            AND t.MaxDate = o.Date
```

The rub is that Purchase Order dates are stored at the header level and there are no dates in the detail data. I have to LEFT JOIN in the max(OrderDate) from the POHeader table and that's where I'm having trouble.

I've tried to compound in the OrderDate from the POHeader table but my code is wrong. Here's where I stopped. ***Can someone help my out with this statement please?***:

```
SELECT d.PartNum, h.MaxDate, d.UnitCost
    FROM 
    PODetail d
    Left Join POHeader h ON 
    (SELECT PONum, MAX(OrderDate) as MaxDate
              FROM POHeader
              GROUP BY PONum) t
        INNER JOIN POHeader o
            ON t.PONum = o.PONum
                AND t.MaxDate = o.OrderDate
```

Here's some fool-around data...

```
create table POHeader (POnum int, OrderDate date);
insert into POHeader (PONum, OrderDate) values (12508, '05/13/2010');
insert into POHeader (PONum, OrderDate) values (12690, '06/04/2010');
insert into POHeader (PONum, OrderDate) values (12847, '09/08/2010');
create table PODetail (PONum int, PartNum varchar(15), Descript varchar(60), UnitCost numeric(10,2));
insert into PODetail (PONum, PartNum, Descript, UnitCost) values (12508, 'X37-BC055', 'PIPE, Titanium (MIL-T-9046), 3"OD x 8FT x .0125"', 6647.18);
insert into PODetail (PONum, PartNum, Descript, UnitCost) values (12690, 'X37-BC055', 'PIPE, Titanium (MIL-T-9046), 3"OD x 8FT x .0125"', 6651.90);
insert into PODetail (PONum, PartNum, Descript, UnitCost) values (12847, 'X37-BC055', 'PIPE, Titanium (MIL-T-9046), 3"OD x 8FT x .0125"', 6713.65);
insert into PODetail (PONum, PartNum, Descript, UnitCost) values (12690, 'N76-18824-ABN', 'COLLAR, Titanium (AMS 4902), 3"ID Flange', 564.13);
insert into PODetail (PONum, PartNum, Descript, UnitCost) values (12847, 'N76-18824-ABN', 'COLLAR, Titanium (AMS 4902), 3"ID Flange', 571.26);
```

You can see in the history data that I bought the 8-foot pipe three times and the collar twice. I'm trying to get to this result - the very last time I bought each part:

```
PartNum        Max Date   Last Price
-------------  ---------- ----------
X37-BC055      9/08/2010     6713.65
N76-18824-ABN  6/04/2010      571.26
```

Thanks for your help,
JM

Comment: I'm rather lost on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I need the LAST price of all parts in PODetail from the last time each part was bought. Except the DATE of each buy is in POHeader, not in the detail.

Comment: What database do you use? Tag your question

Comment: Progress 10 with OpenEdge generic ODBC driver. I'm using WinSQL Lite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the Last Dates and then join to the tables:

```
select d.partnum PartNum, c.orderdate MaxDate, d.unitcost LastPrice
from podetail d 
inner join poheader h on h.ponum = d.ponum
inner join (
  select d.partnum, max(h.orderdate) orderdate
  from podetail d inner join poheader h
  on h.ponum = d.ponum
  group by d.partnum
) c on c.partnum = d.partnum and c.orderdate = h.orderdate
```

Comment: Sorry forpas. I saw your tag request and added "Progress". This database does not support CTE. Is it possible to go old-school with just joins?

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()` which support max dbms

```
   select * from
    (select ph.*,PartNum,UnitCost as lstPrice,row_number() over(partition by PartNum order by OrderDate desc) rn
   from POHeader ph INNER JOIN POdetail po
    ON ph.PONum = po.PONum
    ) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: my SQL Editor is showing a syntax error near POHeader in your third line. The statement won't run.

Comment: @JohnJoseph i missed from to write in query

Comment: Also ON should be ph.PONum = po.PONum

Comment: That's it! Thanks. Is it possible without the row_number over partition? My database is not SQL Server, it is Progress Open Edge with a generic ODBC driver. I am using WinSQL Lite.